# How to put media controller button on notification bar?

Tags: android, mediacontroller, android-music-player

I am creating a music player application. I want to show the media controller on notification bar while my application is running in background. It looks like Google player.

[image]

How to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For getting media player controller in your app simply follow this:

**Call this method in your MainActivity**

```
public void showNotification(View view){
        new MyNotification(this);
        finish();
    }
```

**Create a new MynotificationClass**

```
public class MyNotification extends Notification {

private Context ctx;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public MyNotification(Context ctx){
    super();
    this.ctx=ctx;
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
    CharSequence tickerText = "Shortcuts";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(ctx);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Notification notification=builder.getNotification();
    notification.when=when;
    notification.tickerText=tickerText;
    notification.icon=R.drawable.ic_launcher;

    RemoteViews contentView=new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.messageview);

    //set the button listeners
    setListeners(contentView);

    notification.contentView = contentView;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    CharSequence contentTitle = "From Shortcuts";
    mNotificationManager.notify(548853, notification);
}

public void setListeners(RemoteViews view){
    //radio listener
    Intent radio=new Intent(ctx,HelperActivity.class);
    radio.putExtra("DO", "radio");
    PendingIntent pRadio = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, radio, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.radio, pRadio);

    //volume listener
    Intent volume=new Intent(ctx, HelperActivity.class);
    volume.putExtra("DO", "volume");
    PendingIntent pVolume = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 1, volume, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.volume, pVolume);

    //reboot listener
    Intent reboot=new Intent(ctx, HelperActivity.class);
    reboot.putExtra("DO", "reboot");
    PendingIntent pReboot = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 5, reboot, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.reboot, pReboot);

    //top listener
    Intent top=new Intent(ctx, HelperActivity.class);
    top.putExtra("DO", "top");
    PendingIntent pTop = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 3, top, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.top, pTop);*/

    //app listener
    Intent app=new Intent(ctx, com.example.demo.HelperActivity.class);
    app.putExtra("DO", "app");
    PendingIntent pApp = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 4, app, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn1, pApp);
}

}
```

**Create a HelperActivity class**

```
public class HelperActivity extends Activity {

private HelperActivity ctx;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ctx = this;
    String action = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("DO");
    if (action.equals("radio")) {
        //Your code
    } else if (action.equals("volume")) {
        //Your code
    } else if (action.equals("reboot")) {
        //Your code
    } else if (action.equals("top")) {
        //Your code
    } else if (action.equals("app")) {
        //Your code
    }

    if (!action.equals("reboot"))
        finish();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

**XML layout for Notificationlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/msglbl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/msglbl" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="play" android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: great, but what do i have to deliver as "view" to showNotification() ?

Comment: @texNewbie View is needed if you use this function with an android:onClick listener. If not, you can remove it.

Comment: How can I disable the notification bar from closing when I press any of the buttons, just as Google Music is capable of?

Comment: It's better that HelperActivity extends IntentService

Answer (score 21):

Here is the example above done correctly to the new API

In your main, when you want to start a notification instantiate the class:

```
NotificationPanel nPanel = new NotificationPanel(MyActivity);
```

And when you want to cancel notification: (as it is an onGoing notification)

```
nPanel.notificationCancel();
```

Then create the class for the notification caller:

```
public class NotificationPanel {

private Context parent;
private NotificationManager nManager;
private NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder;
private RemoteViews remoteView;

public NotificationPanel(Context parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.parent = parent;
    nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(parent)
    .setContentTitle("Parking Meter")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setOngoing(true);

    remoteView = new RemoteViews(parent.getPackageName(), R.layout.notificationview);

    //set the button listeners
    setListeners(remoteView);
    nBuilder.setContent(remoteView);

    nManager = (NotificationManager) parent.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nManager.notify(2, nBuilder.build());
}

public void setListeners(RemoteViews view){
    //listener 1
    Intent volume = new Intent(parent,NotificationReturnSlot.class);
    volume.putExtra("DO", "volume");
    PendingIntent btn1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(parent, 0, volume, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn1, btn1);

    //listener 2
    Intent stop = new Intent(parent, NotificationReturnSlot.class);
    stop.putExtra("DO", "stop");
    PendingIntent btn2 = PendingIntent.getActivity(parent, 1, stop, 0);
    view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btn2, btn2);
}

public void notificationCancel() {
    nManager.cancel(2);
}
}
```

Then add the return class that accept the pending intent:

```
public class NotificationReturnSlot extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String action = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("DO");
    if (action.equals("volume")) {
        Log.i("NotificationReturnSlot", "volume");
        //Your code
     } else if (action.equals("stopNotification")) {
         //Your code
        Log.i("NotificationReturnSlot", "stopNotification");
     }
     finish();
    }
}
```

Then you need to make a XML file for the button. This is a simple one:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="volume" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Stop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/msglbl" />
```

Last and not least, the Manifest file:

```
   <activity android:name=".NotificationReturnSlot"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:taskAffinity=""
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>
```

Comment: How to create the Notification? Just use "new NotificationPanel(this);" ?

Comment: I am not able to open new activity on click of button of layout.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me..How can I provide play/pause functionality with single button using this code?

Comment: Thanks! your last piece of code help me to prevent activity from relaunch every time that button pressed in notification. I search for hours after solution.

Comment: Thanks! please note that there is typo... GIVEN:    android:excludeFromRecents="true">  
SHOULD BE:     android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>, see the "/" at the end

Comment: For this case, Its better that NotificationReturnSlot extends IntentService. If it extends Activity, it will display a layout being created and removed

Answer (score 1):

Return/send data from notification to your original Activity; the changes needed for the Example above:

```
NotificationPanel nPanel = new NotificationPanel(MyActivity)
```

How to use the Notification Button to resume the same Stack and Activity that created the Notification:

1) Make sure the Activity is not Destroyed (optional), change the Back button to put the task in the back and not destroy it:

```
@Override    
void onBackPressed() {
   Log.d("onBackPressed", "onBackPressed Called");
   moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

2) In the Menifest add this to the Activity:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

3) Add those flags for your Intent Instance: (volume is the Intent instance)

```
Intent volume = new Intent(....);
....
volume.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
volume.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

and as well you can add the following (optional):

```
volume.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
volume.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
```

4) In the PendingIntent instance don't use any flags:

```
PendingIntent btn1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(parent, 0, volume, 0);
```

5) And catch the intent in your Activity with onNewIntent(Intent intent) call back:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    Log.i("onNewIntent", intent.toString());    // DEBUG - very useful
    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {   // As the Intent we send back has extras, if it don't, it is a different Intent. it is possible to use TRY {} CATCH{} for this as well to find if Extras is NULL.
        String tmp;
        tmp = intent.getExtras().getString("DO");
        if (tmp != null) {  
            if (tmp.equals("volume"))
                Log.i("onNewIntent", "Volume");
            else if (tmp.equals("stop"))
                Log.i("onNewIntent", "Stop");
            else
                Log.i("onNewIntent", "Didnt capture the extras of the Intent - " + tmp);
        } else {
            Log.i("onNewIntent", "No new Intent");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a RemoteView and show it as a notification.

Please refer to the follow document

[Status Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) (Creating a Custom Notification Layout)

Comment: By implementing it, I could only display those buttons. But how to use event listener for them?

Comment: Please check "setOnClickPendingIntent".