# How to add button to notifications in android?

Tags: android, button, widget, notifications

My app plays music and when users open notifications screen by swiping from the top of the screen ( or generally from the bottom right of the screen on tablets ), I want to present them a button to stop the currently playing music and start it again if they want.

I am not planning to put a widget on the user's home screen, but just into notifications. How can I do this?

Comment: i am sorry in that case

Comment: How is this not a valid question ffs?

Comment: Some people just downvote meaningfull questions , but why

Comment: This is the top result in my Google search and no answers...

Comment: Here could have been an answer. You got to love SO and their  rules.

Comment: This is a totally valid question and I have zero understanding for everybody who voted to close this.

Answer (score 18):

You can create an intent for the action (in this case stop playing) and then add it as an action button to your notification.

```
Intent snoozeIntent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
snoozeIntent.setAction(ACTION_SNOOZE);
snoozeIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
PendingIntent snoozePendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, snoozeIntent, 0);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!")
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_snooze, getString(R.string.snooze),
                snoozePendingIntent);
```

Please refer to [the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html#Actions).

Comment: To improve your answer, you will add "text" without icon. Ppease orovide way to create the intent, add icon button to the notification area and join both, then how to receive the intent.

Comment: What's ACTION_SNOOZE?

Answer (score 7):

I will try to provide a solution that I have used and most of the music player also use the same technique to show player controls in notification bar.

I am running a service which is used to manage Media Player and all its controls. Activity User control interacts with Service by sending Intents to the service for example

```
 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyRadioService.class);
        i.setAction(Constants.Player.ACTION_PAUSE);

        startService(i);
```

TO receive intents and perform action in Service class I am using following code in onStartCommand method of Service

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.Player.ACTION_PAUSE)) {
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            pauseAudio();
        }
    }
```

Now to exact answer to your question to show notification with playing controls. You can call following methods to show notification with controls.

```
   //    showNotification
private void startAppInForeground() {
//  Start Service in Foreground

    // Using RemoteViews to bind custom layouts into Notification
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.notification_status_bar);

// Define play control intent 
   Intent playIntent = new Intent(this, MyRadioService.class);
    playIntent.setAction(Constants.Player.ACTION_PLAY);

// Use the above play intent to set into PendingIntent
    PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
            playIntent, 0);

// binding play button from layout to pending play intent defined above 
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.status_bar_play, pplayIntent);
views.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_bar_play,
            R.drawable.status_bg);

Notification status = null;
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        status = new Notification.Builder(this).build();
    }

  status.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    status.icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    status.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
    startForeground(Constants.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, status);
```

}
Hope this really helps you. And you will be able to achieve what you want. Have a Happy Coding :)

Comment: I didn't try it. But it seems the only `complete` answer that `fit` to the user case.

Comment: This code will throw nullpointerexception in any android bellow Jelly Bean

Answer (score 4):

```
    // It shows buttons on lock screen (notification).

Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.NotIcon)
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_prev, "button1",ButtonOneScreen) 
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause, "button2", ButtonTwoScreen)  
   .....
    .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle()
    .setShowActionsInCompactView(1)
    .setMediaSession(mMediaSession.getSessionToken())
    .setContentTitle("your choice")
    .setContentText("Again your choice")
    .setLargeIcon(buttonIcon)
    .build();
```

Please refer this for more details [Click here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Answer (score 4):

tested, working code with android Pie. These all go inside the same service class.

Show a notification:

```
public void setNotification() {

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("a", "status", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
    channel.setDescription("notifications");
    notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    }
else
    notificationManager =  (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


Receiver.service = this;
Notification.MediaStyle style = new Notification.MediaStyle();

notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Notification")
        .addAction(R.drawable.close_icon,  "quit_action", makePendingIntent("quit_action"))
        .setStyle(style);

style.setShowActionsInCompactView(0);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
    notification.setChannelId("a");
    }

// notificationManager.notify(123 , notification.build()); // pre-oreo
startForeground(126, notification.getNotification());
}
```

Helper function:

```
public PendingIntent makePendingIntent(String name)
    {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FloatingViewService.Receiver.class);
    intent.setAction(name);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    return pendingIntent;
    }
```

To handle the actions:

```
static public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
static FloatingViewService service;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

    String whichAction = intent.getAction();

    switch (whichAction)
        {

        case "quit_action":
            service.stopForeground(true);
            service.stopSelf();
            return;

        }

    }
}
```

You'll need to update your manifest too:

```
<receiver android:name=".FloatingViewService$Receiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="quit_action" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that beside  `Ankit Gupta` answer, you can use [MediaSession](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession.html)  (API > 21) to add native [mediaController](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaController.html) view :

```
notificationBuilder
        .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle()
            .setShowActionsInCompactView(new int[]{playPauseButtonPosition})  // show only play/pause in compact view
            .setMediaSession(mSessionToken))
        .setColor(mNotificationColor)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
        .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
        .setUsesChronometer(true)
        .setContentIntent(createContentIntent(description)) // Create an intent that would open the UI when user clicks the notification
        .setContentTitle(description.getTitle())
        .setContentText(description.getSubtitle())
        .setLargeIcon(art);
```

Source: [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession.html)

you can alse  create custom view and display it in the notificcation area , first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526228/how-to-put-media-controller-button-on-notification-bar) is great.

Answer (score 1):

you can add button as below and can perform action on that button also i have done for me as below please check.

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentTitle(name)
                        .setContentText(body)
                        .setGroupSummary(true)
                        .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_directions, "Mark as read", morePendingIntent);
```

//morePendingIntent(do your stuff)

```
  PendingIntent morePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        this,
                        REQUEST_CODE_MORE,
                        new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class)
                                .putExtra(KEY_INTENT_MORE, REQUEST_CODE_MORE)
                                .putExtra("bundle", object.toString()),
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the right way or not, but it works.

1. Create a `BroadCastReceiver` class to receive the data when button is pressed.

```
public class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        
        String log = "URI: " + intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME);
        Log.d("my", "LOG:::::::" + log);
    }
}
```

2. Now in any activity where you want to create the notification -

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("unique_id");
        intent.putExtra("key", "any data you want to send when button is pressed");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
```

3. Now use this pending intent when you are creating the notification and lastly you need to register this broadcast in order to receive it in MyBroadCastReceiver class.

```
BroadcastReceiver br = new MyBroadCastReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("unique_id");
        registerReceiver(br, filter);
```

Now if you want to do certain things when the button is pressed, you can do so in the `onReceive()` method in `MyBroadCastReceiver` class.