# How i put Buttons in Notification for MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I want to develop a **Media Player** where I want to add buttons for notification like **Play-Pause, Next, Previous**. I am unable to understand, how  can I do that ?
I can see buttons for notification but they are not working. Guys please help me out with sample example code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add button to notifications in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195800/how-to-add-button-to-notifications-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can add action buttons in notification as of **Android 4.1**

See this for [Android Notification reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

And you can see **[Code example Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10959343/3884250) and [Here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/android-notification-with-sound-and-icon-tutorial.html)**