# Android: programmatically adding buttons to notification

Tags: android, notifications, remoteview

I am trying programmatically add Imagebuttons to notification, but I cannot find work method for this. I know this is possible, because I saw [similar app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.j4velin.notificationToggle)

This is how I build notification:

```
public class MyNotification extends Notification {
private Context ctx;

public Context getCtx() {
    return ctx;
}

private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;


public MyNotification(Context ctx, int layout_id) {
    super();
    this.ctx = ctx;
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(ns);
    CharSequence tickerText = "Shortcuts";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(ctx);
    Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
    notification.when = when;
    notification.tickerText = tickerText;
    notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;



    RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), layout_id);



    //set button listners
    setListeners(contentView);

    notification.contentView = contentView;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    mNotificationManager.notify(1387, notification);

}
```

And how i try to add ImageButton

```
  RemoteViews button = new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.image_btn_layout_test);


    Intent actionIntent = new Intent("MyIntent");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 0, actionIntent, 0);
    button.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.image, pendingIntent);

    contentView.addView(R.layout.noti_layout, button);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read through these questions:

[How to add button to notifications in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195800/how-to-add-button-to-notifications-in-android)
[Adding button action in custom notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21925688/adding-button-action-in-custom-notification)
[Handling buttons inside android notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438209/handling-buttons-inside-android-notifications)

Also take look at the [Notification Actions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Actions) developers guide.

Also it looks like after a notification is created you cannot add actions, so you should create new notification with specified actions, and then replace previous one (assign id to your notifications).

Comment: I add buttons before creating notification