# Trigger function on notification action click

Tags: android, notifications, kotlin, android-notifications, notification-action

I am writing an app in Kotlin that should display a notification with an action button.

I have a class. Let's call it `NotificationClass`

This class creates notifications for me via `fun createNotification()`

This all works fine. But I want to add a button to the notification that, when clicked, triggers a function in my `NotificationClass` called `notificationActionClicked()`.

Is there a way I can do this?

(The notification class is not an android service. It's just an utility class.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add button to notifications in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16195800/how-to-add-button-to-notifications-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

you need to take look about pending intent

```
 public void createNotification(View view) {
    // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
    // notification is selected
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceive.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    // Build notification
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
            .setContentText("Subject").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Call", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "More", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "And more", pIntent).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

}
```