# App crashes onResume when canceling Notification

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I try to cancel my Notification in onResume() but it crashes:

With displayNotification() i create the Notification. I also tried to set the cancelNotification() in a try catch. But this doesn't solve the problem. But without i can't even start the app to generate the Notification.

Here are my Codesnippets:

OnResume:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() //activity was resumed and is visible again 
    {
        Log.d(logtag,"onResume() called");
        super.onResume();
        cancelNotification();
    }
```

cancelNotification():

```
protected void cancelNotification() 
    {
        Log.i("Cancel", "notification");
        mNotificationManager.cancel(1);
    }
```

displayNotification():

```
protected void displayNotification(String message, String ticker) 
    {
        Log.i("Start", "notification");

        /* Invoking the default notification service */
        NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = 
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);   

        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Neue Nachricht!");
        mBuilder.setContentText(message);
        mBuilder.setTicker(ticker);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        /* Increase notification number every time a new notification arrives */
        mBuilder.setNumber(++numMessages);

        /* Creates an explicit intent for an Activity in your app */
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);

        /* Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack */
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
            0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        /* notificationID allows you to update the notification later on. */
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Error:

```
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.blauzahn/com.example.blauzahn.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2120)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at com.example.blauzahn.MainActivity.cancelNotification(MainActivity.java:388)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at com.example.blauzahn.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:976)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
10-23 17:27:35.763: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  ... 12 more
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not cancel on onPause() ?

Comment: because the notification is called, when the activity is not even visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mNotificationManager` is null in `cancelNotification`. Just reinstantiate it:

```
protected void cancelNotification() {
    Log.i("Cancel", "notification");
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.cancel(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@EgnorN's answer is right on target: `mNotificationManager` is null in `cancelNotification()`.

To add some broader lessons:

1. We can debug problems like this from the stack trace:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
      at ...cancelNotification(MainActivity.java:388)
      at ...onResume(MainActivity.java:976)
```

This indicates that the program ran afoul of a null value in `cancelNotification()` in MainActivity.java on line 388. That must be:

```
    mNotificationManager.cancel(1);
```

`mNotificationManager` must be null to cause that.

If there are multiple things that could be null on the given line, one can use a debugger breakpoint to stop at that line and look at the different values. Alternatively, break it into multiple lines and run again to see which line throws the exception.

2. If you change the code to get the NotificationManager in each method that needs it and hold it in a local variable rather than keeping it in an instance variable, that will avoid a category of similar problems where the code incorrectly assumes that the Activity's instance variables are still set.

In any case, do read up on the [Activity life cycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html). It's important to know when the Activity instance gets created and deleted.

3. If you're building your project with the API 21 version of the support.v4.app library, you can make your code a little simpler, more type safe, and more backwards compatible by using the newly added method `NotificationManagerCompat.from(Context)` to get a NotificationManagerCompat, which is like a NotificationManager plus fallbacks for older platforms.

Comment: i have some buttons disabled and enabled, before i minimize my app. By pressing on the app button in the menu, the app resumes and the buttons are just like i set them. But by clicking on the notification in the Activity-bar the app opens with the default buttonset. Do you know how to prevent this?

Comment: This is a new question but in brief, the Activity's state depends on how you build the PendingIntent to go there from the Notification (see e.g. http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation.html#DirectEntry) whether the Activity saves and restores state (see e.g. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html), and maybe more factors.