# How to put media controller button on notification bar with cordova-based application?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic-framework

I am creating a hybrid music player application based on cordova for Android and iOS. I want to show the media controller on notification bar while my application is running in background. I've found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526228/how-to-put-media-controller-button-on-notification-bar), but for a native app.

Is that achievable?

Comment: try use cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Comment: Can I customize the notification I have? For example, adding buttons to it...