# create my music control in notification

Tags: android

I am creating a simple app which can play music from a url. There is no forward or backward button.. Just play and the music will stream from url and will be played..
I need that control in notification when i click play button where in notification a close button also should be show to stop the music and clear the notification.
How could i implement it.. 
my Code in Music is

```
 /** This method initialise all the views in project*/
    private void initView() {
        buttonPlayPause = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause);
        buttonPlayPause.setOnClickListener(this);

        seekBarProgress = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.SeekBarTestPlay);
        seekBarProgress.setMax(99); // It means 100% .0-99
        seekBarProgress.setOnTouchListener(this);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    }

    /** Method which updates the SeekBar primary progress by current song playing position*/
    private void primarySeekBarProgressUpdater() {
        seekBarProgress.setProgress((int)(((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()/mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds)*100)); // This math construction give a percentage of "was playing"/"song length"
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
        if(v.getId() == R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause){

            /** ImageButton onClick event handler. Method which start/pause mediaplayer playing */
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioUrl); // setup song from https://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3 URL to mediaplayer data source
                mediaPlayer.prepare(); // you must call this method after setup the datasource in setDataSource method. After calling prepare() the instance of MediaPlayer starts load data from URL to internal buffer.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mediaPlayer.getDuration(); // gets the song length in milliseconds from URL

            if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.start();
                buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_pause);
            }else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
            }

            primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.SeekBarTestPlay){
            /** Seekbar onTouch event handler. Method which seeks MediaPlayer to seekBar primary progress position*/
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)v;
                int playPositionInMillisecconds = (mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds / 100) * sb.getProgress();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPositionInMillisecconds);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        /** MediaPlayer onCompletion event handler. Method which calls then song playing is complete*/
        buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_play);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        /** Method which updates the SeekBar secondary progress by current song loading from URL position*/
        seekBarProgress.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put media controller button on notification bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526228/how-to-put-media-controller-button-on-notification-bar)

Comment: @Youngjae Yeah but thats not working for me!! Activity crashes